# What is _convertNSDictionaryToDictionary<A, B where ...> (NSDictionary?) -> [A : B] and why is it crashing my app?

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics

I have the following Swift code:

```swift
class ThingChecker {
    static func checkThing() -> [String: [String]] {
        return Thing.stringsDictionary()
    }
}
```

Where `Thing` is a class implemented in Objective-C with the following interface:

```objc
@interface Thing : NSObject

+ (NSDictionary<NSString *, NSArray<NSString *> *> * _Nonnull)stringsDictionary;

@end
```

But when I run my app and call `ThingChecker.checkThing()`, my app crashes with the following error:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode 0x0)

Nothing useful prints in the console.  It just shows `(lldb)`.

[image]

The only thing even remotely useful looking is found in the debugger's stack trace.  I can see two frames in the stack that might give a bit of a clue.  First, just below my code is:

```
_convertNSDictionaryToDictionary<A, B where ...> (NSDictionary?) -> [A : B]
```

And just below that, I see:

```
_arrayForceCast<A, B> ([A]) -> [B]
```

But clicking on either of these just points to assembly code.

What's going on here?  What is causing this crash?  I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the Objective-C code you are wrapping.

Whoever wrote the Objective-C interface was kind enough to add the generics annotations so that you get more useful type information.

Without the generics (and nullability) annotations, someone might have lazily written the interface as such:

```objc
+ (NSDictionary *)stringsDictionary;
```

Which is irritating, because in Swift that quite inconveniently ends up with the following signature:

```swift
class func stringsDictionary() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]!
```

But with the generics and nullability annotations added to the Objective-C code, as such:

```objc
+ (NSDictionary<NSString *, NSArray<NSString *> *> * _Nonnull)stringsDictionary;
```

We end up with a much easier to digest Swift signature:

```swift
class func stringsDictionary() -> [String: [String]]
```

It's clear that this is a dictionary with string keys and arrays of strings as values.

But Objective-C annotations are not strictly enforced in Objective-C code.  They're merely suggestions.  And those generics annotations aren't strictly enforced until we bridge out to the Swift side of things.

So in the process of bridging by means of applying these Objective-C generics annotations, Swift calls through the method mentioned in your question:

```
_convertNSDictionaryToDictionary<A, B where ...> (NSDictionary?) -> [A : B]
```

This is how the `NSDictionary` from Objective-C is converted to the Swift dictionary.  But if the *actual* contents of the dictionary don't match the generics signature (and the type which Swift therefore infers the type to be), you will get this crash.

Effectively, this crash is roughly equivalent to the crash you'd get if you tried using the `as!` operator and the cast failed.

For example:

```swift
let someDict: AnyObject = ["foo": ["a", "b", "c"], "bar": [1, 2, 3]]
let stringDict = someDict as! [String: [String]]
```

This cast would fail and your app would crash because `someDict` can't be interpreted as `[String: [String]]`.  At best, it could be interpreted as `[String: [Any]]`.

So, if for example, the implementation of that Objective-C method looks like this:

```objc
+ (NSDictionary<NSString *, NSArray<NSString *> *> * _Nonnull)stringsDictionary {
    return @{ @"foo": @[@"foo1", @"foo2", @"foo3", @"foo4", @"foo5"],
              @"bar": @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5],
              @"baz": @[@"baz1", @"baz2", @"baz3", @"baz4", @"baz5"] };
}
```

Trying to call this method from Swift generates the exact error message, because the value for the key `@"bar"` it an array of `NSNumber` objects, so at best, this would be able to be treated as a `[String: [Any]]` in Swift.

And we can fix the Objective-C generic annotations as such:

```
+ (NSDictionary<NSString *, NSArray *> * _Nonnull)stringsDictionary;
```

Or, we could fix the implementation and get rid of the value that appears to be wrong (since the method is called `stringsDictionary` and `NSNumber` values are clearly not strings).